# Create folder inside Downloads or Documents Android API 33

Tags: android

My Use case needs me to implement a code which writes text files to the storage in a public folder.

I need a folder inside either Downloads or Documents inside which I can save the txt files.

The current code that I have which works is

```
 File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File newDir = new File(path + "/<folder_name>");
        try{
            if (!newDir.exists()) {
                newDir.mkdir();
            }
```

I see from the documentation that `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` was deprecated in API 29.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)

I've seen some posts on SO but they include prompting the user to choose where to save the files, which is not an option for me.
I need to create the folder and txt file in the background as the purpose is for logging (enterprise app - non playstore)

Comment: If it's for logging, why don't you use the app private storage? Why do you need it to be in a public folder?

Comment: Also, have you tried the alternatives offered in the documentation: _Note that alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String) or MediaStore offer better performance._ at the end of [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

Comment: As I mentioned it's an enterprise application and that's the requirement layed down by the client. If android doesn't allow the same I need to provide the relevant documentation so I'm asking for help on SO. Thanks!

Comment: @Adinia getExternalFilesDir provides the path inside /android/data which doesn't fit my requirement. Haven't got an implementation solution to create a folder using MediaStore. Thanks!

Comment: if (!newDir.exists()) {
                if (  !newDir.mkdir() ) return;
            }

Comment: just remember that if you put something in downloads, the user can delete it, and are quite likely to if they don't know what it is.  You could, by convention, start your filename with a dot and most file browsers will hide it.  MOST.  If there is a chance of the app being uninstalled, then the user data for the app would be cleared as well, but that is absolutely where you should put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK mkdir() is not deprecated.

On the root folder structure of the internal storage i.e where

/Android /DCIM /Documents /Downloads exists,
you can't create folders in API33+ minSDK

but within Downloads or Documents you can create the folders.

As getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(..) is deprecated I used [getPrimaryStorageVolume(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager#getPrimaryStorageVolume()) to get absolute path

```
String filePath = String.format("%1s/%2s/%3s", getInternalStorageDirectoryPath(this), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"newFolder");

        File newDir = new File(filePath);
        if (!newDir.exists()) {
            newDir.mkdir();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(new File(newDir, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));
            writer.write(data.getBytes());
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



public static String getInternalStorageDirectoryPath(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
            return storageManager.getPrimaryStorageVolume().getDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i did this exactly as you did but in sdk 33+ gives me err ,
Operation not permitted :'(

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!newDir.exists()) { if ( !newDir.mkdir() ) return; } –
```

For the rest your code is ok.

And the deprecation has been released.

And on an Android 33 device you do not need any permission.

Comment: I don't follow, It still shows deprecated as of api 29 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String) . For getting the path to create the folder instead of getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() what can I use?